# Android circular button with circular text

Tags: android

I am currently trying to create a circular button here but, there is a circular text in the border. In that particular screen, I will need to create 9 similar buttons in a 3x3 grid. I have tried to create the circular text programmatically but could not position it properly with the button.

Would appreciate the help I can get. Thanks

[image]

Comment: use photo shop to create your buttons.

Comment: use an image to do that...

Comment: Alright. Was just wondering if there is any way to do it programmatically as I do not have to worry about resizing the buttons to a different size and fit different screen densities.